# How can i scrape data from twitter and have more than 8 rows of data returned?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I am trying to scrape data from twitter for a research, it could tell me over 20,000 results in search information but only displays 8 rows when i display.

i used an actual API but i did not insert here. I decided not to use tweepy because of its limtation.

Everything seems to be working just fine except that limitof only 8 rows of Data

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re

twitter_data = []

payload = {
    'api_key':'',  #i used an actual API but i did not insert here
    'query':'e-commerce',
    'num':'10000000'        
}
response = requests.get(
    'https://api.scraperapi.com/structured/twitter/search', params=payload)


data = response.json()

all_tweets = data['organic_results']
```

The result I got was:

```
[{'position': 0,
  'title': 'Ecommerce',
  'snippet': 'Spotify this morning announced a new partnership with e-commerce platform provider Shopify that will allow artists on its service to connect their Spotify.',
  'highlighs': ['e-commerce'],
  'link': 'https://twitter.com/ecommerce',
  'displayed_link': 'https://twitter.com › ecommerce'},
 {'position': 1,
  'title': 'Q&A: How an e-commerce brand created a community on ...',
  'snippet': 'Q&A: How an e-commerce brand created a community on Twitter ... As a purely online business, how do you connect with existing customers and establish\xa0...',
  'highlighs': ['e-commerce'],
  'link': 'https://business.twitter.com/en/blog/how-e-commerce-brand-created-community.html',
  'displayed_link': 'https://business.twitter.com › blog › how-e-commerc...'},
 {'position': 2,
  'title': 'Here are my tips for navigating the e-commerce revolution.',
  'tags': '2 days ago —',
  'snippet': '2 days ago — Here are my tips for navigating the e-commerce revolution. ... digital landscape, businesses must embrace e-commerce strategies to thrive.',
  'highlighs': ['e-commerce', 'e-commerce'],
  'link': 'https://twitter.com/Inc/status/1696890382313836580',
  'displayed_link': 'https://twitter.com › Inc › status'},
 {'position': 3,
  'title': 'Educative',
  'tags': 'Aug 11, 2023 —',
  'snippet': 'Aug 11, 2023 — E-Commerce web apps are fueling business transformation. Online transactions have become the norm. Discover how to build a professional\xa0...',
  'highlighs': ['E-Commerce'],
  'link': 'https://twitter.com/EducativeInc/status/1690044160424792064',
  'displayed_link': 'https://twitter.com › EducativeInc › status'},
 {'position': 4,
  'title': 'UNCTAD E-Commerce and Digital Economy',
  'snippet': 'UNCTAD E-Commerce and Digital Economy. @ECDEatUNCTAD. E-Commerce and Digital Economy Branch. @UNCTAD . We work on #ecommerce #DigitalEconomy #eTradeForAll\xa0...',
  'highlighs': ['E-Commerce', 'E-Commerce'],
  'link': 'https://twitter.com/ECDEatUNCTAD',
  'displayed_link': 'https://twitter.com › ECDEatUNCTAD'},
 {'position': 5,
  'title': 'e-Commerce News HQ (@eCommerceNewsH1) / Twitter',
  'snippet': 'YouTube Introduces Official Shopify Integration | e-Commerce News HQ. Last week, YouTube dropped some pretty exciting eCommerce news on their official blog.',
  'highlighs': ['e-Commerce'],
  'link': 'https://twitter.com/eCommerceNewsH1',
  'displayed_link': 'https://twitter.com › eCommerceNewsH1'},
 {'position': 6,
  'title': 'Starting an e-commerce business takes more than just a ...',
  'tags': 'Jan 11, 2023 —',
  'snippet': 'Jan 11, 2023 — Starting an e-commerce business takes more than just a great product. It requires persistence, background work, and the willingness to\xa0...',
  'highlighs': ['e-commerce'],
  'link': 'https://twitter.com/Inc/status/1613262294376488970',
  'displayed_link': 'https://twitter.com › Inc › status'},
 {'position': 7,
  'title': 'Boston Consulting Group',
  'snippet': "E-commerce pure play doesn't require the heavy outsourcing that other approaches to e-commerce may call for, making it easier for an organization to\xa0...",
  'highlighs': ['E-commerce', 'e-commerce'],
  'link': 'https://twitter.com/BCG/status/1478969586401824769?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw',
  'displayed_link': 'https://twitter.com › BCG › status'},
 {'position': 8,
  'title': 'CBP Office of Trade',
  'tags': 'Apr 19, 2023 —',
  'snippet': 'Apr 19, 2023 — is strengthening its ability to address the increase in e-commerce, the national and economic security threats this poses, and more.',
  'highlighs': ['e-commerce'],
  'link': 'https://twitter.com/CBPTradeGov/status/1648694234336186368',
  'displayed_link': 'https://twitter.com › CBPTradeGov › status'}]
```

This keeps happening for any search I do.

Comment: You're not scrapping twitter, you're scrapping `api.scraperapi.com` si I guess that the 8 limit is either because they have a limit in the `num` parameter and since you're trying to request more than they allow they change it to 8 or maybe they just have a limit of 8 for your API key or in general. https://docs.scraperapi.com/python/ https://www.scraperapi.com/quick-start-guides/python-requests-beautifulsoup-scraper/

Comment: I tested NUM=100. The API returned 100 data but START=100 for next page. It did not works. I think the `scraperapi` API is not support a paging parameter at all.